# Referencing images to show on hover that aren't included in the project

Tags: jquery, html, image, onhover

I'm working on a website where I don't control the content and have no idea what content is coming in (which is why I can't store the images)
What I want is to when a class is referenced, grab the data-image reference and then when that class is hovered over, it displays the image that is referenced.

```
<span class="myCard" data-image="http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=386589&type=card">Mantis</span>
```

So I thought something like:

```
$('.myCard').mouseenter(function () {
            var img = new image();
            img.src = $(this).attr("data-image");
            $(img).show();
        });
```

but I can't get it to work, where am I going wrong? Or is there a better way to do it?

P.S. there will be multiple images in the document so I can't hard code anything in either.

Thanks

Comment: You aren't appending anywhere your image, so... And anyway, `new image();` must be `new Image();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the image to the dom. You can append it anywhere, in this example it is added to the span:

```
$('.myCard').mouseenter(function () {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = $(this).attr("data-image");
   $(this).append(img);
});
```

Check the jsfiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/7r8prns0/)

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code -

```js
$('.myCard').mouseenter(function () {
          var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
          img.attr('src', $(this).attr("data-image"));
          img.appendTo($(this));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="myCard" data-image="http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=386589&type=card">Mantis</span>
```